# How to find out the length of a varchar parameter in a postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find out the parameter length for a varchar parameter passed into a postgres function.

The SQL I have just now has no values in the character_maximum_length column where I would have expected to find this value

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.parameters 
WHERE specific_schema='public' 
   AND specific_name  like 'foo' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think postgresql keeps this information. If I `create function foo(varchar(100)) returns boolean ...` and then dump the schema with `pg_dump`, I find:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(character varying) RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE sql
    AS $$select true$$;
```

The '100' specification is gone. And passing a 150-character string to foo(varchar) is not trapped or anything. By contrast, if I create a domain based on varchar(100) and define the function in terms of that, then passing an overlong string is trapped.